# In the Find My App - why does Macbook show a random time in the middle of the night?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, find-my-mac

I have family sharing on, and one of my own laptops was showing a timestamp of 3am, but I was asleep then.

Will a macbook ever periodically "ping" its location, or is it exclusively when it is being requested? I asked all my family members if anyone was awake then and looking at the app, but everyone said they were asleep.

Is there another reason that a macbook may show a time when it's not actively in use, or if its location is not being requested?

Comment: Maybe it was checking for macOS updates? Just a guess. You could look to see when it last checked for an update.

Comment: @JBallin thanks - do you know where I can see a history of when it last checked for an update?

Comment: This is assuming you have auto updates on - it displays the last time checked on the bottom when you visit “Software Update” from system preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds exactly what Power Nap would do when it wakes to check in on pending iCloud actions.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-is-power-nap-mh40773/mac

> Power Nap, available on Mac computers with flash memory, lets some Mac computers stay up to date even while they’re sleeping.

There are apps that specialize in helping you visualize all the things that can stop your machine from idling and/or sleeping. The best is https://ohanaware.com/sleepaid/

[Here are some tips if you want to try and DIY this](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/06/30/dealing-with-the-insomniac-mac/) using the `pmset` command.

Comment: Anyone know if there's a way to check in Console for example, of a Power Nap process taking place around that time? What might that log message look like?

Comment: Open console. If you see any diagnostic messages, you know the system is running. When I’m back at the mac, I can try to get the syntax for `pmset -pslog` Apple used to have a KB on diagnosing sleep wake issues and documented how to open terminal.app and leave that running so you can inspect all the dark wakes and normal wakes from sleep, @bahrieinn